# Dragging a view across pages in an infinite UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have troubles with dragging views across pages in a subclass of my infinite scroll view as once the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method gets called, the view gets stuck at `0,0` coordinates. Here is the full picture:

I have a custom subclass of `UIScrollView` (paging enabled) that keeps an index and every time it scrolls it asks its dataSource for a new view for the given index. It starts at `[-1][0][1]` where user can only see `[0]`. Once the user scrolls right, `[-1]` is removed from superview, `[0]` and `[1]` moved and page `[2]` generated to give `[0][1][2]`. This works perfect as I am using it as a calendar that scrolls infinitely. In this calendar I want to be able to drag appointments across weeks. This is done using `UIGestureRecogniser` - the user holds the appointment view for 1 second which triggers the `UIGestureRecogniser` and I then use the `[gesture locationInView:self]` to update the position of the appointment view.

When the user drags to the side of the view, the scroll moves to show the next page. Since appointment views are subviews of the page in which they belong, this means I need to move the appointment to the scroll itself (`[scroll addSubview:appointmentView];`) which keeps the `UIGestureRecogniser` working well. However, as original position of the appointment view was given using autolayout and I cannot afford to remove parent constraints with `[appointmentView removeFromSuperview];` as it would stop the `UIGestureRecogniser`, I have to cycle through all parent constraints and check whether is `firstItem` or `secondItem` equal to `appointmentView`. Again, this works well when scrolling within the original page although the `appointmentView` is now a subview of the scroll rather than the page.

At this point the user drags the `appointmentView` to the side and my scroll moves to show the next week (each page shows a week). This time, however, the `appointmentView briefly` moves to `(0,0)` for a split second, however `UIGestureRecogniser` is still working so if I keep moving my finger, the `appointmentView` will return to moving across the screen. At this point, assuming the `appointmentView` comes from page 0, its page is on the left and the centered page is page 1 - `[0][1][2]`.

At last here comes the problem: if the user moves one week further to the right, the `appointmentView`'s original page (page 0) gets removed as the scroll now shows `[1][2][3]` and appointmentView jumps to `(0,0)` of the scroll and `UIGestureRecogniser` is terminated immediately without running through its selector with state as `UIGestureRecogniserStateEnded`.

I am 99.9% certain there are no remaining parental constraints linking the `appointmentView` to its original parent page 0 which means I have no idea why removing page 0 causes this behaviour. The `appointmentView` only has constraints on itself (width and height) and on its subviews (labels within the view) which means laying out the views should have no effect on the `appointmentView`'s location; and yet...

My ideas so far:

1. I know that if I create a brand new `appointmentView` and add it directly to the scroll so it has no link to a week page, it behaves properly without any issues. That means if there is a way to trigger the `UIGestureRecogniser` programatically, I could simply do the following. When the user holds the `appointmentView` for a second I can delete the old `appointmentView`, create a new one and add it at the same location, trigger its `UIGestureRecogniser` and then simply follow the user's finger with the new `appointmentView`. However, I don't see a way of doing this without the user lifting the finger from the screen.
2. Maybe I am still somehow forgetting some parent constraint that causes the `appointmentView` to go crazy when its original parent is removed but I don't see how this could be possible. It only has 4 constraints: x coordinate based on the fraction of the width of the page and the day on which the appointment is; y coordinate based on the fraction of the height of the page and the starting time of the appointment; width as a fraction of the width of the page; height as a fraction of the height of the page. I clearly remove all 4 of these and I have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false
3. Give up and cry in the corner

Any input on this would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the thing, the problem occured when the original parent view was released so I simply kept it in a variable throughout the moving process and released it once the dragging was completed.